# Any difference or drawback of using $MyInvocation instead of $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation

Tags: powershell

Is there any difference or drawback when always using `$MyInvocation` or `$PSBoundParameters` instead of `$PSCmdlet.MyInvocation` or `$PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters` respectively?

I already had a look at the following things:

- Searched the internet (obviously)
- [about_automatic_variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables)

  - There the following is written:

  > $MyInvocation is populated only for scripts, function, and script blocks.

  - Furthermore, I know that the `$PSCmdlet` variable is only available when using `[CmdletBinding()]` and a `param ()` block.
  - It looks like these variables were added quite some time ago (PowerShell v2.0?).
- Then, I executed the following code within different contexts:

  ```
  $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.Equals($MyInvocation)
  $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters.Equals($PSBoundParameters)
  ```

  These lines return `true` in all the following cases (all files contain `[CmdletBinding()]` and `param ()`):

  - Directly executed in a script
  - When executed in a script via the call operator (`&`)
  - When executed in a module cmdlet

So, is it recommended (and safe) to use `$MyInvocation` and `$PSBoundParameters` in every possible situation (i.e. script, function, module, etc.)? And do they always return the same values as the `$PSCmdlet.*` counterparts (assuming that `[CmdletBinding()]` is given)?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "recommended [..] to use [..] in every possible situation", but it is certainly _safe_ - they indeed always resolve to the same as the `$PSCmdlet` members and they're both available in all version of the scripting language (2.0 through 7.x, PowerShell 1.0 had no real scripting language beyond basic command invocation syntax).